# "bscured by a filter driver" error from Google Drive File Stream

Tags: windows-10, google-drive-file-stream

Google Drive File Stream gives me errors in the event log on Windows 10.
What do they mean and when can I do to remove them?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>  Get-EventLog -Newest 50 -LogName "System" -Source "googledrivefs2356"

   Index Time          EntryType   Source                 InstanceID Message
   ----- ----          ---------   ------                 ---------- -------
   19068 Jan 09 08:57  Error       googledrivefs2356      3221618690 The driver version of the disk does not match.
   19067 Jan 09 08:57  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 Mounting disk device.
   19035 Jan 09 08:54  Error       googledrivefs2356      3221618690 bscured by a filter driver.
   19034 Jan 09 08:54  Error       googledrivefs2356      3221618690 ng mounted. If this prevents DriveFS startup, it may mean the DriveFS device has its identity o
   19033 Jan 09 08:54  Error       googledrivefs2356      3221618690 Not mounting because there is no matching DCB. This is expected, if a non-DriveFS device is bei
   19032 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 The DCB type is actually f653a7a0; expected 3a474342.
   19031 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 Processing the lower level DeviceObject, in case this is a DriveFS device wrapped by a filter.
   19030 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 The DCB type is actually f78a1030; expected 3a474342.
   19029 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 Processing the lower level DeviceObject, in case this is a DriveFS device wrapped by a filter.
   19028 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 The DCB type is actually f6546c90; expected 3a474342.
   19027 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 Processing the lower level DeviceObject, in case this is a DriveFS device wrapped by a filter.
   19026 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 The DCB type is actually f6382620; expected 3a474342.
   19025 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 Processing the lower level DeviceObject, in case this is a DriveFS device wrapped by a filter.
   19024 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 The DCB type is actually f78bf0c0; expected 3a474342.
   19023 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 Mounting disk device.
   19016 Jan 09 08:54  Error       googledrivefs2356      3221618690 bscured by a filter driver.
   19015 Jan 09 08:54  Error       googledrivefs2356      3221618690 ng mounted. If this prevents DriveFS startup, it may mean the DriveFS device has its identity o
   19014 Jan 09 08:54  Error       googledrivefs2356      3221618690 Not mounting because there is no matching DCB. This is expected, if a non-DriveFS device is bei
   19013 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 The DCB type is actually f653a7a0; expected 3a474342.
   19012 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 Processing the lower level DeviceObject, in case this is a DriveFS device wrapped by a filter.
   19011 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 The DCB type is actually f78a1030; expected 3a474342.
   19010 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 Processing the lower level DeviceObject, in case this is a DriveFS device wrapped by a filter.
   19009 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 The DCB type is actually f6546c90; expected 3a474342.
   19008 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 Processing the lower level DeviceObject, in case this is a DriveFS device wrapped by a filter.
   19007 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 The DCB type is actually f6382620; expected 3a474342.
   19006 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 Processing the lower level DeviceObject, in case this is a DriveFS device wrapped by a filter.
   19005 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 The DCB type is actually f78bf0c0; expected 3a474342.
   19004 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 Mounting disk device.
   18997 Jan 09 08:54  Error       googledrivefs2356      3221618690 bscured by a filter driver.
   18996 Jan 09 08:54  Error       googledrivefs2356      3221618690 ng mounted. If this prevents DriveFS startup, it may mean the DriveFS device has its identity o
   18995 Jan 09 08:54  Error       googledrivefs2356      3221618690 Not mounting because there is no matching DCB. This is expected, if a non-DriveFS device is bei
   18994 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 The DCB type is actually f653a7a0; expected 3a474342.
   18993 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 Processing the lower level DeviceObject, in case this is a DriveFS device wrapped by a filter.
   18992 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 The DCB type is actually f78a1030; expected 3a474342.
   18991 Jan 09 08:54  Information googledrivefs2356      1074135041 Processing the lower level DeviceObject, in case this is a DriveFS device wrapped by a filter.
```

Comment: I have similar errors... even after uninstalling googledrivefs and google drive. It's due to some low-level mounting mistake that Google did.. and didn't clean up.